# Выборка слова НЕ между символами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо выбрать слова из текста, которые находятся НЕ между квадратных скобок.

К примеру текст:
[test **Word** text] **Word**

Из него нужно выбрать второй **Word**, но не тот, который находится между скобок.
Можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: а из текста `[[test Word text] Word` что нужно выбрать? а из текста `[test Word text] Word]`? p.s. подсказка: вы неправильно формулируете требование в контексте рег. выражений. вам надо **удалить** что-то, а не «выбрать».

Comment: ну и поразмышляйте над ещё чуть более сложным примером: `[test Word text] Word [test Word text] Word`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin к последнему: между скобок - это между [ и ], но никак не ] и [

Comment: Я бы сформулировал так: выбрать слова из текста, слева от которых не находится символ [ ближе, чем ], и справа  от которых не находится символ ] ближе, чем [.

Comment: Вообще, какая разница, который из **Word** добывать, если они одинаковые? И зачем его вообще добывать, если он известен?

Comment: `'[test Word text] Word'.split(/\s*\[.+?\]\s*/).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: @АлексейР это ТС так приколько вопрос сформулировал. Из "[test Work text] Word" нужно добыть слово Word, но не test, Work или text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log('[test Work text] [] Word []'.match(/\w+(?![^[]*\])/g))
```

Comment: '[test Work text] [] Word []'? Или это будет слишком широкое понимание задачи?

Comment: @rotabor, да, исправил.

Comment: '[test Work text] [ Word []'? Опять же не уверен в понимании условия.

Comment: @rotabor, если могут быть вложенные скобки, то регулярками это не решается. По крайней мере, не на js. В вопросе не сказано, что скобки могут вкладываться.